# Objective C Category & Two Classes

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have 2 classes:

- `XCALayer` derived from `CALayer`
- `XCATextLayer` derived from `CATextLayer`

I've created `XCALayer+FrameMucking.h` category that allows me easily adjust `XCALayer`'s frame. The thing is that I would like to use it also for `XCATextLayer`, but without duplicating all the code. Is it possible to use my category for both `XCALayer` and `XCATextLayer`?

Comment: You could create a third class containing the implementation and then make the category methods call into this third class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just changing the frame of `XCALayer` and `XCATextLayer` you should be able to add a category to `CALayer` since `frame` is a property of `CALayer`.